# Phonegap whitelist domains for Android

Tags: android, cordova, content-security-policy, phonegap

Using phonegap version 6.5.2 I'm trying to whitelist domains for an Android application's data and media requests.

In config.xml I have:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

as well as a few specific domains:

```
<access origin="http://example.com" />
<access origin="http://fonts.googleapis.com" />
```

I've also tried putting this in my root `index.html`, which should allow all domains, right?:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

But I'm still getting nothing but 404 errors when my app tries to load content.

What gives?

Comment: Not quite sure if this is a csp issue. If it was I'd expect an error like _Refused to load ... because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: ..._

Comment: What else could be causing 404 errors on xhr and media requests? The app works fine on iOS and in a browser, the URLs being asked for are definitely there. How would I go about debugging further to figure out what's blocking it?

Comment: Good question. You could try running your app without any CSP to ensure it's a CSP problem.

Comment: @nicholas cordova whitelist plugin installed?

Comment: I've tried taking out all CSP tags in the config.xml and index.html and get the line in the console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Comment: @Gandhi That's a good point. I installed the whitelist plugin with `phonegap plugin install ...`, then `phonegap prepare`. I do see the plugin in my config.xml and references to it scattered through the android project. How could I tell if it is working in the android build?

Comment: @nicholas now are you able to get away with 404 errors?

Comment: @Gandhi No. The plugin was already installed like I outlined. The 404 errors are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic rule to follow in case of 404 errors in cordova android app are as follows:

- Check whether cordova whitelist plugin is installed properly
- Check whether allow access origin is set properly in config.xml
- Check whether content security policy is set properly in your HTML
  files

These steps should address almost all the problems related to 404 errors provided the requested URLs are up and running. Hope it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the problem was, but after uninstalling and re-installing the whitelist plugin, and restarting the simulator, everything seems to be working. Thanks @Gandhi for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: posted my answer